# Как вызвать функцию C в программе на C++?

Tags: c++

Как вызвать функцию C в программе на C++?

Comment: Просто вызываете её подключив необходимую библиотеку.

Comment: Если у вас вопрос конкретнее, то опишите его подробнее, а ещё лучше добавьте код.

Comment: просто вызвать и все

Comment: Добавьте в С++ коде `extern "C"` перед прототипом вызываемой функции.

Answer (score 0):

подключить заголовочный файл модуля написанного на C

```
extern "C"{
#include "headr.h"
}
```

вызвать функцию

```
extern "C"{
 some_C_func();
}
```

Comment: но по хорошему лучше писать класс обертку.

Comment: Для вызова `extern "C"` не нужен (и не скомпилируется).